# Bad turn off signal for mosfet

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

Currently, I'm designing Zeta Converter for my projects and I made this design. [image]

When there is no supply applied to the zeta converter, the PWM signal seems good.
[image]

But it ends up getting a bad turn-off signal
like this picture when the supply applied
[image]

edited:
so each channel are connected to PWM1/PWM2 & SOURCE to see how PWM signals are. PWM1/PWM2 are connected to the GATE of MOSFETS and SOURCE are connected to the SOURCE of MOSFETS

[image: connector power to ic]

Comment: Please show layout, and preferably a photo of where the probes are connected and oriented.

Comment: sorry, I just edited the post. please take a look

Comment: A schematic of the gate driver circuit would be very interesting.

Comment: For the gate driver circuit, you can see it in the schematic I posted. At the top right of the picture

Comment: Apparently the ground of scope (or scope's GND lead) is disturbed. Is there any physical connection between the scope's ground and IN– of the circuit? Try isolating the GND of the scope (from it's power cord) and re-take the measurements.

Comment: Is the power supply IC+/IC- isolated from the power supply you use to power the rest of your circuit, ie. IN+/IN-? When the power is off, what happens if you use your multimeter to test for continuity between IC- and IN-? Is the ground of your power supplies isolated from the ground of the scope? Also, I take it you do have shunt resistors on your board for the current shunt amplifiers. They aren't shown on the schematic.

Comment: There was no straight physical connection between the scope's ground and IN-. But, because this is Zeta Converter, IC-/ SOURCE is somehow connected to IN- through the L1 (inductor)

Comment: I test for continuity between IC- and IN- with a multimeter and it is beeping. The only reason that IC- and IN- are connected is through inductor L1

Comment: Trying to switch off a MOSFET too fast by pulling it low through diodes D1 & D2 can cause ringing due to common source inductance and gate loop inductance. R=47Ohm (U3 & U5) is enough to dampen the oscillation, but try taking out the diodes. Also, decrease the gate loop inductance by twisting the wires that goes from the gate drive isolator (HCPL3120). Instead of having one wire "Source" add wires Source1 and Source2. Twist each one with PWM1 and PWM2 respectively. Source1/2 connect eventually close to a common point "Source" near the isolator.

Comment: I have tried removing the diodes, but it didn't help. Also, I don't understand by twisting the wires that goes from the gate drive isolator, sorry my English is just not that good. So this design is already printed into a PCB.

Comment: Before I print this design into a PCB, I was tested it with perforated PCB and It was good

Comment: Can you perhaps add a photo of the PCB showing the connections of the power supplies connecting to the board?

Comment: Is the gate measurement between source and gate or between ground and gate?

Comment: @GLK the gate measurement was between source and gate. The problem is still exist until now.

Answer (score 0):

If the circuit is made on a solderless breadboard then the capacitance and inductance of the rows of contacts and the wires all over the place make oscillation like you show.

Comment: I'm not using a solderless breadboard. The first experiment was using perforated PCB and it work. Then I printed it into a PCB.